# GET not printing when there is another GET after it?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-ise

I've gt this script to automate removal of users for our workplace and I can't figure out why this Get doesn't print anything if there is another get after it. Is this a delay issue? or there a problem with my syntax"

```
    #Requests user input username
    $_Name=Read-Host "Enter account name you wish to disable"

    #Lists the users AD groups and removes them
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_Name | select name
    Get-ADUser -Identity $_Name -Properties MemberOf -Credential $_Creds| ForEach-Object {
        $_.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Credential $_Creds -Confirm:$false
    }   
    write-host "User has been removed from the listed groups..."
```

It just returns a blank space where the list should be.

Comment: from the help for that cmdlet [emphasis mine] [*grin*] ... `-PassThru - Returns an object representing the item with which you are working.` _**By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output_**.

Answer (score 0):

To extrapolate what was mentioned in the comments:

You are currently running two separate Get commands. The first one, `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` will generate output. It's a list of groups a principal is member of. The second Get command you're running (`Get-ADUser`) has it's output used in a loop and you're not printing that output. You'd need to do something like `Write-Output $_.MemberOf` to see it.

You're using `$_.MemberOf` as another input to the command [`Remove-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/Remove-ADGroupMember?view=win10-ps). For that command the documentation states:

> Outputs
>
> None or Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup
>
> Returns the modified group object when the PassThru parameter is specified. By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output.

So unless you supply the parameter `-PassThru` it will consume the "output" of `$_.MemberOf` and not display anything.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused, where would I use the -PassThru?

Comment: On the `Remove-ADGroupMember` as it's part of the documentation for that command.